# Shibboleth IDP 4 login failed:

Tags: shibboleth

i need your help. I'm trying to connect to moodle  with the Shibboleth Login but it doesn't  work. I checked the file idp-process.log and i am getting this error and don't know what its meaning?

**< Unable to resolve outbound message endpoint for relying party 'http://172.16.98.98/shibboleth': EndpointCriterion.>**
Im using OpenLdap and moodle .
i have checked all metadata from idp and sp but nothing .

I hope that somebody will help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to resolve outbound message endpoint for relying party 'http://172.16.98.98/shibboleth': EndpointCriterion.>

I *think* what this means is that the shibboleth software is unable to resolve the intended URL and have it turn into a reachable endpoint. So you want to make sure this address is in fact available, reachable and preferably an HTTPS url.